# audio not playing properly

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

```
var sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "lion", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tiger", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fox", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound4 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "zebra", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound5 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "koala", ofType: "mp3")!)

var imageview = UIImageView()
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var sound : [NSURL] = [sound1,sound2,sound3,sound4,sound5]
    let height = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
    horizontalscroll.frame = view.frame
    for i in 0 ..< receiveimg.count
    {

        imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.image = receiveimg[i]
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let xvalue = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageview.frame = CGRect(x: xvalue, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - height!)


        horizontalscroll.contentSize.width = horizontalscroll.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
        horizontalscroll.addSubview(imageview)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound[i] as! URL)
            audioPlayer.play()
        }

        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    horizontalscroll.isPagingEnabled = true
```

i have a scroll view in which it has a uiimage view ,on scrolling it shows 5 different messages, it should also play 5 different audios while scrolling, but only one audio is playing at 1st image that too the last audio. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You code to play is not played on scrolling, it's played directly on populating the scrollview. Also, you don't wait for the end of the current item to play to load the other one.

Comment: which delegate method should i put it ?